# Does Visual Studio 2015 have a Resharper Equivalent to CTRL+T fast object find?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2015, resharper-9.2

Does anyone know?  I am finding that Resharper 9.2 is very buggy with testing and burping.  But the funny thing is that I use Resharper the most for a little function of CTRL + T.  It brings up a quick find where you type and it in real time searches methods, classes, test classes, etc for what you are typing.  So if I am working on an enterprise solution with 50 plus projects and each project can have dozens of classes it is easier to use this.

I was wondering now that Visual Studio 2015 has in essence done some of what Resharper did with mapping diagraming and removing and adding references if it could do this.  I know you can find by name above the solution explorer or hit CTRL + SHIFT + F to find in the files.  But these are kind of slow so I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

I was using this reference: http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/ and tried some things but did not find what I thought I was looking for by searching for 'Find', 'Retrieve', 'Get' in the shortcuts.  It may be named something I am not aware of.

Comment: Edit->Navigate To: Ctrl+, (comma)

Comment: @pharring Thanks. I'd lost the binding for whatever reason and needed to reassign it.

Comment: For anyone using VS2017 or above: 'Navigate to' is now 'Edit.GotoAll'. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/52432/navigate-to-shortcut-stopped-working.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

VS's CTRL+comma solves the majority of the use case that Resharper's CTRL+T does, and is supported in previous versions (I'm currently on 2013 and have no complaints using it to zip around large solutions).

As a bonus, if you hit CTRL+comma on an interface type, it'll bring both that type and any concrete types that implement it up in the list, invaluable when dealing with tests and mocks, DI-injected method signatures etc.

Comment: Thanks that is what I needed.